# Microsoft Excel Splitting rows in a column into a separate column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a couple of thousand rows of data in Excel where each logical record uses two rows, with the Job/Eqp number and the Job Name in column C on alternating rows.  I want to move the Job Name data into column D and delete the unnecessary rows, leaving a more logical layout of one record per row.  This is what the data looks like now:

```
        Column A     Column B    Column C
Row 1   Date:        Employee:   Job/Eqp:
Row 2   07/10/2014   Jeremy      2014042
Row 3                            LABCORP GAITHERSBURG
Row 4   07/10/2014               2013002
Row 5                            DULLES LANDING
Row 6   07/11/2014               2013002
Row 7                            ONE LOUDOUN BUILDING P
Row 8   07/11/2014               2014049
Row 9                            ELITE SHOOTING SPORTS
```

This is what I'd like to have:

```
        Column A     Column B    Column C    Column D
Row 1   Date:        Employee:   Job/Eqp:   Job Name:
Row 2   07/10/2014   Jeremy      2014042    LABCORP GAITHERSBURG
Row 3   07/10/2014               2013002    DULLES LANDING
Row 4   07/11/2014               2013002    ONE LOUDOUN BUILDING P
Row 5   07/11/2014               2014049    ELITE SHOOTING SPORTS
```

No macro or formula I've tried works.

Comment: Could you try and format your question better please, it's very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do this one time, and assuming each logical record has exactly two rows, you don't need a macro.  I'd copy Column C into Column D, then delete the single cell D2, making sure you choose Shift Cells Up.  This will move each Job Name up one line.  Next I'd insert an index column and fill it with 1 through 2000 or whatever number of rows you have.  Suppose you insert the index column in Column E, next you would sort all data by Column A.  All of the alternating rows that have blanks in the date column will be sorted together and can be deleted.  Finally, re-sort all data by the indexing column and you'll be left with the format you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve this with the Power Query Add-In. It takes a couple of steps to get there but no Macro code or changes to your input data structure are required.

I've built a prototype which you can view or download - its "Power Query demo - Splitting rows in a column into a separate column" in my One Drive:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FA287BBC10EC562%21398

Basically my technique was to first build an intermediate query which filters down to every odd-numbered row (not counting the heading), and adds an "Index Row Pairs" column to keep track of the row pairs.  Then I created duplicate of that Query, which filters down to the even-numbered rows.  Then I used a Merge to join (on the "Index Row Pairs" column) to the first Query and get the Eqp column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is alwas a date in column A (in the first of the two rows in each group), this macro should do it:

```
Sub CreateNewColumn()
Const dataSheetName As String = "Sheet1"

Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastCellInColumnA As Range
Dim totalNoOfRows As Long
Dim autoFillSource As Range
Dim autoFillTarget As Range
Dim rowIndex As Long

Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dataSheetName)
dataSheet.Range("D1").Value = "Job Name:"
dataSheet.Range("D2").Formula = "=C3"
totalNoOfRows = dataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Don't include blank rows at the end
totalNoOfRows = dataSheet.Range("A" & CStr(totalNoOfRows + 1)).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
'Set lastCellInColumnA = Sheet1!Range("A" & CStr(totalNoOfRows))

Set autoFillSource = dataSheet.Range("D2")
Set autoFillTarget = dataSheet.Range("D2:D" & CStr(totalNoOfRows))
autoFillSource.AutoFill autoFillTarget
dataSheet.Calculate
autoFillTarget.Copy
autoFillTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

For rowIndex = totalNoOfRows To 2 Step -1
    If Len(dataSheet.Range("A" & CStr(rowIndex))) = 0 Then
        dataSheet.Rows(rowIndex).Delete
    End If
Next rowIndex

ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```